# Event emitter stops executing

Tags: jquery

If "myEvent" receiver gets an exception during execution, event emitter stops executing. Is it normal that event emitter depends on receivers?

```js
$(window).on("myEvent", () => {
  throw "Boo"
});
$(window).trigger("myEvent");
console.log("never comes here");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes this is normal. Do you have a specific issue? It seems a try/catch would solve the problem if you are expecting execution to continue.

Comment: So for me it is strange design. Why should emitter care what receivers do? How should it know how to handle exceptions? I suppose that exceptions should be limited to receivers.

Comment: I would say that would be legit design if receiver would be expecting result. It seems to me that this behaviour is dictated by JS it self. So OK I will swallow exceptions manually :)

Comment: Please answer my question. I will accept cruel reality as it is... :)